# String replace in SQL Server 2008. I want to rename "Ä?" to "c"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I use string replace in SQL Server? I want to rename "Ä?" to "c"

For example:

```
roÄ?no_orodje_unior_1600e1.jpg -> rocno_orodje_unior_1600e1.jpg
```

and here also string replace "Ä?" to "c" and remove everything beyond,

```
roÄ?no_orodje_unior_1913.jpg,roÄ?no_orodje_unior_1 -> rocno_orodje_unior_1913.jpg
```

Can I do this with SQL Server or must I use C# ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the replace function...example

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(100) = N'roÄ?no_orodje_unior_1600e1.jpg'

SELECT REPLACE(@s,N'Ä?',N'c')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(n'roÄ?no_orodje_unior_1600e1.jpg',n'Ä',n'c');
```

You second example does not appear to do what you saying you want it to do.  If it were removing everything beyond `Ä` then it would be `roÄ` correct?